# How to import modules ,Class Names dynamically in python PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

My attempt is to try to import modules and their depending classes dynamically. Here is my code.  File **"Sample_tabwidget_base.py"** have three classes names "Contact", "Personal" and "Educational".  And I need to import all those classes into my file **"sample_tabwidget.py"** dynamically. Googleing so many items and trying them, But lack of knowledge, I can't succeed.

**File : sample_tabwidget.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
# from sample_tabwidget_base import *
import importlib
module = importlib.import_module('sample_tabwidget_base')
print(module.__doc__)

# class_ = getattr(module)
# module = __import__("sample_tabwidget_base")
# mod = getattr(module,'Contact')
# print(mod)

class MainPage(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("QTabWidget Samples")
        self.showMaximized()
        self.subwindow = None
        self.Ui()
        self.show()


    def Ui(self):

        self.tab = QTabWidget()
        self.tab.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tab.setTabShape(QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.tab.setTabPosition(QTabWidget.North)
        self.tab.setMovable(True)
        self.tab.setDocumentMode(True)
        self.tab.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.tab.setStyleSheet(stylesheet())
        font = self.tab.font()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.tab.setFont(font)

        self.right_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout = QHBoxLayout()

        self.right_frame = QFrame()
        self.right_frame.setObjectName("rightframe")
        self.right_frame.setStyleSheet(f"QFrame#rightframe{{background-color: lightgreen;}}")
        self.right_frame.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        self.right_frame.setLayout(self.right_layout)
        self.right_layout.setContentsMargins(15,0,0,0)
        self.right_layout.addWidget(self.tab)

        self.main_layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.right_frame)
        self.main_layout.addStretch()

        self.contacttab = Contact()
        self.personaltab = Personal()
        self.educationaltab = Educational()
        
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.tab.addTab(self.contacttab, "Contacts")
        self.tab.addTab(self.personaltab,"Personal")
        self.tab.addTab(self.educationaltab,"Educational")

def stylesheet():

    return """
      QTabBar {background-color: grey;}

      QTabWidget::pane {border: 0px solid yellow; top:-1px; background: grey; }

      QTabBar::tab:hover{background-color:yellow;}

      QTabBar::tab {background-color: grey; color : black;
                    border-left: 1px solid grey;border-top:1px solid grey;border-right:1px solid grey;
                    text-align:centre ;  font-family:Trebuchet MS; padding : 10px; }
  
      QTabBar::tab:selected {background: lightgrey;color : Black;border-bottom:5px solid red;margin-bottom: -1px;
                             text-align:centre ;  font-family:Trebuchet MS; color:Black; padding : 10px;}
    """

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = MainPage()
    app.setStyle("windows vista")
    mainwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**File : smaple_tabwidget_base.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Contact(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("its a contact class")
        self.setWindowTitle("Contact Details")
        self.layout = QFormLayout()
        self.layout.addRow("Name", QLineEdit())
        self.layout.addRow("Address", QLineEdit())
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

class Personal(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Personal Details")
        self.layout = QFormLayout()
        self.sex = QHBoxLayout()
        self.sex.addWidget(QRadioButton("Male"))
        self.sex.addWidget(QRadioButton("Female"))
        self.layout.addRow(QLabel("Sex"), self.sex)
        self.layout.addRow("Date of Birth", QLineEdit())
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

class Educational(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Educational Details")
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(QLabel("subjects"))
        self.layout.addWidget(QCheckBox("Physics"))
        self.layout.addWidget(QCheckBox("Maths"))
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
```

Comment: And why do you need to do that?

Comment: Are you sure you got the spelling right? In your question, you (mis)spelled it in three different ways. What specific errors do you get (if any)? You need to ensure that the `sample_mainpage_tabwidget_base.py` file (or whatever it's actually called), is in the same directory as the main script (i.e. the one you used to start the program).

Comment: @musicamante ,I think, if I can import packages, modules, and classes dynamically, then it's a more user-friendly package, so I try to achieve it. For example, if possible to load class dynamically, then users will develop their own solution and include it in packages.

Comment: @ekhumoro, typo error corrected, I use "sample_tabwidget_base.py" as my file name.  I got NameError: name 'Contact is not defined. Yes both the file in the same directory

Comment: If the module is imported without error, you can do e.g. `self.contacttab = getattr(module, 'Contact')()`.

Comment: @Bala dynamic loading makes sense only for these 2 conditions: 1. you have **lots** of modules (in the order of *hundreds*) that could actually take a lot of time to load; 2. those modules are part of a "plugin system" that allows custom installation from the user, and for which you cannot have any direct control at implementation level. Based on your question/code, you don't need **any** of that, and it looks to me that you're just trying to implement some sort of optimization that only makes your code unnecessarily convoluted and uglier. That is not optimization, it's just pointless.